# Read two char from array as one hex number in C

Tags: c, arrays, char, int, hex

So I am working on an encryption/decryption project .
What I want to do is read in 2 characters from the line, and use them as one hex number to decrypt to the original hex value, and print to a file accordingly the proper ascii character value.. here's my code :

```
sscanf(lineFromFile, "%2C", tmp);

//check carriage return new line as per outline
if(strcmp(tmp, "\n") == 0) {
    fprintf(output, "%c", tmp);
}
//Check for tab whcih is set to TT in encryption scheme
if (strcmp(tmp, "TT") == 0) {
    fprintf(output, "\t");
}
else {
    outchar = ((tmp + i*2) + 16);
    if (outchar > 127) {
        outchar = (outchar - 144) + 32;
    }
    fprintf(output, "%C", outchar); //print directly to file
}
```

Comment: carriage return is `'\r'`, newline is `'\n'`.  `"/n"` is just slash & n

Comment: check out `strtol`.

Comment: What is `i`? What is `((tmp + i*2) + 16)` supposed to be?

Comment: `((tmp + i*2) + 16)` is equivalent to `&tmp[i*2 + 16]`. But since `tmp` only contains 2 characters, you're accessing outside the initialized portion.

Comment: @Barmar this is in a loop to check characters til it reaches the end of the line. ((tmp i*2) + 16) was a try at getting it to access two elements of an array at once to add 16 to

Comment: I think you mean `tmp[i*2]+16`.

Comment: That doesn't access two elements at once, though. I think you mean `tmp[i]*16 + tmp[i+1]`

Comment: But if `tmp` contains hex characters, you need to convert them to the corresponding numbers. `'0'` through `'9'` needs to subtract `'0'`, `'a'` through `'f'` needs to subtract `'a'` and add `10`.

Comment: As suggested earlier, you can just use `strtol()`. Or you can use `sscanf()` with `%2x` format.

Answer (score 0):

If you have a string like `str[]="0120";`,
you could do

```
int a, b;
sscanf(str, "%2x%2x", &a, &b);
```

to read the contents of `str` two characters at a time, treat them as hexadecimal numbers and store them into the variables `a` and `b`.

```
printf("\n%d, %d", a, b);
```

would print

```
1, 32
```

`%x` format specifier is used to read as hexadecimal numbers and the `2` in `%2x` is used specify the width.

Now you can use `fprintf()` to write the values to file.

```
fprintf(output, "%d %d", a, b);
```

And you have a typo in the last `printf()`. The format specifier for `char` is `%c` not `%C`. But in this case, I used `%d` as the variables are of type `int`.